# Xamarin.Forms.Mac Commands not invoked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I've got a Page with a ListView displaying some cells with audiodata.

The View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:audioViews="clr-namespace:Lama.Forms.Source.UI.CustomControls.AudioViews;assembly=Lama.Forms"
   x:Class="Lama.Forms.Source.UI.Pages.MainPages.MacOSAudiofileCellView"
   Padding="0" HasShadow="False" >

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,2" Spacing="0">
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectCellCommand}" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

...

        <!-- The Playback Buttons -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Play Button -->
            <Image Source="{Binding PlayButtonIcon}">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <!-- Stop Button -->
            <Image Source="{Binding StopButtonIcon}" Grid.Column="1">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding StopCommand}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Grid>

        <!-- The Grid for Filename, Artist and Title -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- The Filename -->
            <StackLayout Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                         Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Fill">

                <Label Text="Filename:"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       WidthRequest="100"
                       VerticalOptions="Fill"
                       Style="{StaticResource CellLabel}" />

                <Label x:Name="LblFilename" Text="{Binding Filename}"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Fill"
                       Style="{StaticResource CellLabel}"/>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChooseNewFilenameCommand}"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

            </StackLayout>

            <!-- The Artist -->
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChooseNewArtistCommand}"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label Text="Artist:"
                               WidthRequest="100"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               Style="{StaticResource CellLabel}"/>

                <Label Text="{Binding Artist}"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           Style="{StaticResource CellLabel}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            ...
</ViewCell>
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class AudiofileCellViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    #region Commands
    public Command SelectCellCommand { get; }
    public Command ChooseNewFilenameCommand { get; }
    public Command ChooseNewArtistCommand { get; }

    public Command PlayCommand { get; }
    public Command StopCommand { get; }
    #endregion

    #region CTOr
    protected BaseAudiofileCellViewModel()
    {
        SelectCellCommand = new Command(SelectCell);
        ChooseNewFilenameCommand = new Command(async () => await ChooseNewFilename());
        ChooseNewArtistCommand = new Command(ChooseNewArtist);
        ChooseNewTitleCommand = new Command(ChooseNewTitle);
        ChooseNewAlbumCommand = new Command(ChooseNewAlbum);
        ChooseNewCommentCommand = new Command(ChooseNewComment);
        ChooseNewKeyCommand = new Command(ChooseNewKey);
        ChooseNewBpmCommand = new Command(ChooseNewBpm);

        PlayCommand = new Command(async () => await PlayAudiofile());
        StopCommand = new Command(StopAllAudiofiles);
    }
    #endregion
```

There are some Commands defined for the Labels which will invoke on a Tap. This works on Xamarin.Forms.UWP but if I switch to Xamarin.Forms.Mac, they don't fire. I can see that there is something happening via a animated View on the Mainpage which stutters on a Click, but no breakpoint ever gets hit.
I am running the latest stable: Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0.697729

Answer (score 0):

There is no `TapGestureHandler` implementation currently on macOS, actually no Gesture handlers at all since the current macOS platform does not support them. There is a Xamarin written `NSClickGestureRecognizer` but there are issues with it on different Forms controls and how they are implemented on macOS.

It makes sense on UWP as Microsoft has a touch interface implementation not just within UWP, but the operating system itself and if you do not have a touch interface the OS converts mouse/trackpad clicks to "touch-based taps" and the UWP touch API "just" works.

Now in the future macOS Mojave will be supporting iOS apps via Apple porting iOS-only based Frameworks to macOS and thus the **UIKit framework** has been ported and you will be able to use UIKit instead of just AppKit. Thus this will support converting those mouse/trackpad clicks into native `UITapGestureRecognizer` events. I have not dived deep enough in Mojave to see actually how this will done and if AppKit widgets will inherit UIKit abilities, but since you are using `Xamarin.Forms` you would just need to wait till Xamarin supports the new OS features (of course your app would be Mojave only, at least in terms of touch support).

Comment: This cannot be 100% correct, because at other positions in code, my Labels get a TapGestureRecognizer assigned and they do work.

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin You are correct, 1st I meant `TapGestureHandler` not recognizer as there is no native gesture handlers within the Forms' MacOS code line. 2nd there is a custom `NSClickGestureRecognizer` is being used as a substitute with the iOS code line (that is were most of the MacOS renderers live), and while there are areas this is ok, others are sketchy at best... a Forms Label on macOS is actually a  AppKit.NSTextField and "clicks" work on them. Consult the open issues on the Xamarin.Forms regarding this. Personally I have avoided these issues by using my own custom renderers.

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin Just a followup, I know one person that I worked with ended up adding transparent buttons as overlays to make the `TapGestureRecognizer` work correctly on macOS, I just searched the open issues and found this workaround also on a 7/8 month old open bug (different problem, but same workaround)

Comment: This is such a silly workaround :'D Maybe I will update my OS to Mojave to see if it already works there. But why does the TapGestureRecognizer work an some Labels, but not on the ones inside the ViewCell?

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin I would be interested in hearing those results :-) ... I have a Mojave VM running in Parallels, but have not tried any Xamarin.Forms on it... I have been testing Xamarin.Mac built on H.Sierra on it for compatibility testing for some apps.

Comment: After I updated my OS to Mojave, the commands still don't get invoked. So are there any ideas left? :D

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin I do not believe there has been any work done in the Xamarin.Forms implementation for Mojave specific enhancements, would need to review the latest commits (Xamarin.Mac has always had really low usage demographics, I'm still waiting on enhancement requests that were "queued up" from 3+ years ago). I would post an issue on the GitHub Forms' repo and see what the Microsoft reply is.

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin  FYI: Also there is a large Mono/Xamarin.Mac issue (see the GitHub repo issue for details) on Mojave that does not have a stable solution that is causing UI thread rendering issues (my applications are effected and my clients, the ones that upgraded without checking app compatibility, are using High Sierra VMs now to run my apps along with quite a number of other 3rd-party apps that Mojave is causing problems with...